# No bashrc file in my home directory

Tags: bash, bashrc

Here is what I noted down from my lecture:

- Find file `.bashrc` in your home directory
- do `vi .bashrc`
- When you put an application folder somewhere, make sure that its address is in the
  path variable.

The problem is that I do not have a `.bashrc` file in my home directory. There is only a `.bash_history` file in my home.

If i go to the root, there is a `etc/bash.bashrc` file there but what i think is that it will make changes for all users and not just for me. I want to add this path just for myself. It shouldn't effect others. Also there is no `$PATH` variable in that bashrc file so I am even more confused.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Don't forget it is a hidden file inside your home directory (you would not be the first to do a `ls -l` and thinking it is not there).

Do following ...

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

There should be a `.bashrc` on the first page. If not just create it with

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

And simply write following line into it.

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

---

**OR**
Most of the distributions keep a standard `.bashrc` file in `/etc/skel/` You can copy it to home directory.

```
$cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Comment: OK I get that now.
On other computers, I can type lego and the software starts. On my system, the lego folder is in my `~/data/user1/bin` folder. I have added this path to .bashrc file. Now what do I have to do so that when i type lego, it should start the software? Do i have to set up an alias? If yes, how? `alias lego='<What do i put here???>'`

Comment: @detraveller Have you added `~/data/user1/bin` to your PATH environment variable in the `.bashrc` file? (add this line: `export PATH=$PATH:~/data/user1/bin`) - if so, you should be able to just type `lego` in the terminal, and the program should start.

Comment: I added only `PATH=$PATH:~/data/user1/bin`. You didn't mention export so I didn't put it there. I will try again tomorrow when I go to Uni.

Comment: But i was wondering how do i tell bash that `lego` is the word that starts the software?

Comment: The backup of the .bashrc file was a life saver!

Answer (score 15):

Most distributions keep a standard `.bashrc` file in `/etc/skel/` you can just copy to your home dir. Otherwise you could just make a new empty `.bashrc` file in your home dir.

Answer (score 5):

### Create Your Own Startup File for Interactive Shells

#### About Bash Startup Files

From the INVOCATION section of `man 1 bash` says:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
>   reads  and  executes  commands  from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
>   these files exist.

Note that these startup files are *optional*; Bash doesn't require them. Bash also differentiates between login shells and interactive shells. An interactive shell is defined thus:

> An interactive shell is one started without  non-option  arguments  and
>   without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected
>   to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with  the  -i
>   option.

Many distributions source one type of startup file from the other, but some don't, so this issue can be difficult to address canonically. You need to examine all your startup files to see how and when your `~/.bashrc` will be invoked on *your* system.

#### Creating Your Per-User Interactive Shell Startup File

If you're simply missing a user-specific `~/.bashrc` file, just create one. This will be invoked by Bash for non-login shells (e.g. shells started without the `--login` flag), or whenever you force the shell to be interactive by invoking it with the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `.bashrc`, you can simply create one and add the lines you wish to it, such as:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

to add your user bin directory to the end of the path.

But you should be careful if there are *other* startup files. The rules as to what files get used are rather complex, but they're detailed in the `bash` man page. Enter `man bash` on a command line and look for `INVOCATION`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answers:**

1. `find ~  -maxdepth 1  -name '.bashrc'`
2. `vi ~/.bashrc`
3. `echo $PATH | grep ~/MyNewCoolProgramFolder`

**Detailed one:**
I take a more close literal interpretation.

1. ***"Find file .bashrc in your home directory"***
   Since it exists the command `find`, maybe the *treacherous editor* would suggest you to use it:

   ```
   find ~ -maxdepth 1 -name '.bashrc'
   ```

   Search in the home directory `~`, descend only of one level (no subdir `-maxdepth 1`). For all the options write `man find`.
   The line below the will do the minimal job

   ```
   ls ~/.bashrc
   ```

   **Note:** In case `~/.bashrc` doesn't exist **you can create it** with a simple `echo >> ~/.bashrc`.

   The `>>` will create the file if doesn't exists. If the `~/.bashrc` instead exists it will append only the harmless output of empty `echo`, avoiding an unintentional deletion a such critical file, that is incidentally difficult to restore without a backup.

   (The following is because seldom I have to honour the meaning of my nickname, do not execute if you are in doubt).

   ```
   if [ ! -f ~/.bashrc ] ; 
     then
        cp -i /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc ;
     else ls -la ~/.bashrc; 
   fi || echo " # Auto Generated " >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. ***"Do `vi .bashrc`"***
   Now you can do `vi ~/.bashrc`, the trap here is that you need to press <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd> to exit !
3. ***Application folder and `$PATH`***
   When you create an application folder, e.g. `~/MyNewCoolProgramFolder`, the below line will only check if it is in the `$PATH`:

   ```
   echo $PATH | grep ~/MyNewCoolProgramFolder
   ```

   **You do not need to add if is already there.** If needed you can add to the `$PATH` with

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:~/MyNewCoolProgramFolder
   ```

   and to add that line to `~/.bashrc` if you want to make it permanent.
4. ***"4?!? How 4 if there were only 3 points?"- Workarounds.***
   There are some workarounds for the latter; let's suppose an executable file named `CoolDetraveller` exists only in your new application folder:

   (a) You can try to execute it. Simply it will not start if it is not in the `$PATH`.

   > CoolDetraveller: command not found

   (b) You can try its [auto completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). Start to write `CoolDetravelle` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If it is in the `$PATH` it will be auto completed (always if auto completion is enabled).

   (c) You can ask to the bash shell `which` command will be used if you write the command `CoolDetraveller`.

   ```
       which CoolDetraveller
   ```

   **Note:** 
   If in your application path there is one or more spaces, `which` could be unable to find `CoolDetraveller`, although (here I honour my nickname again) the *auto completion* of  `CoolDetraveller` as a valid parameter of the `which` command will work!

   ***Ad nauseam***: You cannot ask `whereis CoolDetraveller` because `whereis`

   > has a hard-coded path, so may not always find what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can open your hidden files from home by
**CTRL + h**

then if you don't find .bashrc there then open terminal and just run following commond

```
/bin/cp etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

and your problem is solved any you may find bashrc file in your hiden files......