# .bashrc: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to edit my `.bashrc` config, but when I try to access the configuration with:

> computer:~ home$ `.bashrc`

I'm getting a: `-bash: /.bashrc: No such file or directory` error.

Why isn't .bashrc working?

(OSX 10.10)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** it is not working because with `.bashrc` you are trying to execute a command named `.bashrc` that has to exist_ somewhere in your `$PATH` and has to be executable.

**How to edit:**
If you want **to edit it**, instead, you should write something like

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or `vim ~/.bashrc` or `emacs ./bashrc` or any other text editor you like; all the changes will be effective the next time you will open an interactive (not login) shell.

**Some words more**:

- **It has to exist** in your `$PATH` and not necessarily in the current directory, because you are using `commandname` and not `./commandname`. The current directory usually is not included in the path for security reasons.
- **It has to be executable** because even if a file with that name is present in one of the directories of your `$PATH`, if it is not executable it will not run.
- This file (`~/.bashrc`)  is commonly used by the shell `bash` when the shell is interactive. It is usually stored in your home directory (you can find it in  `~/.bashrc`) and determines the behaviour of your interactive shells.

  From `man bash`:

  > When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.
- With `. ~/.bashrc` you will [*source*](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) the file *like if you write it line by line* in the shell.
  **Warning** That means that you will run again all the commands inside. It will not forget, for example, an old `alias` present misspelled in the former version of the file...
  For a clean understanding of the behaviour introduced it is better to start a

Further lectures:

- [OS X Server: How to edit configuration files](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202292).

Answer (score 2):

#### .bashrc: command not found

The command you are looking for is

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Note:

- As you seem to be in your home directory already you can omit `~/` from the above commands.

---

#### . (source or dot operator)

> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current
>   shell context.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> . filename [arguments]
>
> source filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> When a script is run using source it runs within the existing shell,
>   any variables created or modified by the script will remain available
>   after the script completes. In contrast if the script is run just as
>   filename, then a separate subshell (with a completely separate set of
>   variables) would be spawned to run the script.
>
> There is a subtle difference between executing a script by running
>   .ss64script (dot ss64script) and . ss64script (dot space ss64script)
>   the first is running a file thats been hidden from the 'ls' command,
>   (although ls -a will show hidden files) the second option will execute
>   ss64script even if it has not been set as an executable with chmod.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) - Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current shell context.

Comment: My-Air:~ myname$ `source ~/.bashrc`

-bash: /Users/myname/.bashrc: No such file or directory ///

My-Air:~ myname$ `. ~/.bashrc`

-bash: /Users/myname/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: If you **don't have** a `~/.bashrc` you need to create one ...

Comment: See [No bashrc file in my home directory](http://superuser.com/a/584542)

Comment: @Hannu ... for this I feel me better to suggest an `echo >>~/.bashrc` to someone who only begins to deal with such kind of problems. With a computer it is so fast to do an irrecoverable mess... :-) The __`>>`__ will create the file if doesn't exists. If the `~/.bashrc` instead exists it will append only the harmless output of empty `echo`, avoiding an unintentional deletion a such critical file, that is incidentally difficult to restore for a newbie without a backup.

Comment: Right! :-]  (x)-ed it...

Comment: OP says: "I'm trying to **edit** my `.bashrc"` -- why an answer recommending `source`?

Comment: @JeremyDouglass Because his question is unclear. I'm explaining the error in his question.